# Retrieve data by date range

Tags: mysql, datetime, mysql-workbench, between

This is the code that i able to get the data of the date 2018-12-12.

```
SELECT COUNT(`table`.`ID`), `table`.`number_Of_Car`
FROM `company`.`table` 
WHERE `table`.`location` <> '' AND `table`.`location` LIKE('%2017-12-12%') 
Group by ...
```

However I tried the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(`table`.`ID`), `table`.`number_Of_Car`
FROM `company`.`table` 
WHERE `table`.`location` <> '' AND `table`.`location` BETWEEN('%2018-12-12%') AND ('%2018-12-13%') 
Group by ...
```

Is there a way I can make the following work?

Comment: Don't use `%`s. Also this isn't PHP related. The `%` are wildcards that the `like` uses.

Comment: What type is the column `table.location` and what does it actually contain? You also can't have `%` in BETWEEN.

Answer (score 1):

If you want data from a particular date, then use:

```
where t.column >= '2017-12-12' and
      t.column < '2017-12-13'
```

If you want multiple dates, just extend the range:

```
where t.column >= '2018-12-12' and
      t.column < '2018-12-14'
```

Do not use `like` for dates.  I cannot fathom why a column called `location` would contain a date.

Comment: Probably just part of the space-time continuum